# Sparql query getting timeout exception

Tags: java, sparql

When I am using this query in java then I am getting HTTP Exception
504 as I am getting data from Live.

But if I remove `influenced` or `influencedBy` or `Paradigm` or anyone of them then it works fine. Then I understood that there is a problem in time or in memory and another problem is now it is too slow. I want them all. What can I do now?

```
SELECT  ?pl  ?pl_label ?abstract ?_thumbnail

           ( group_concat ( DISTINCT ?_influenced_label; separator="; " )   AS ?influenced )
           ( group_concat ( DISTINCT ?_influencedBy_label; separator="; " ) AS ?influencedBy ) 
           ( group_concat ( ?_sameAs; separator=", " ) AS ?sameAs )     
           ( group_concat ( ?_paradigm_label; separator=", " ) AS ?paradigm )

    WHERE
      { 

          ?pl   rdf:type    dbo:ProgrammingLanguage .

          OPTIONAL  { ?pl   dbo:abstract    ?abstract . 

          FILTER ( LANG ( ?abstract ) = 'en' ) . }

          ?pl   rdfs:label      ?pl_label

          FILTER ( LANG ( ?pl_label ) = 'en' ) .

          OPTIONAL      { ?pl   dbo:influenced  ?_influenced . 

          ?_influenced      rdfs:label      ?_influenced_label . 

          FILTER ( LANG ( ?_influenced_label ) = 'en' ) . }

          OPTIONAL  { ?pl   dbo:influencedBy    ?_influencedBy . 

          ?_influencedBy  rdfs:label         ?_influencedBy_label

          FILTER ( LANG ( ?_influencedBy_label ) = 'en' ) . }

          OPTIONAL { ?pl owl:sameAs ?_sameAs . } 

          OPTIONAL { ?pl dbp:paradigm ?_paradigm .

          ?_paradigm rdfs:label ?_paradigm_label . }

          OPTIONAL { ?pl dbo:thumbnail ?_thumbnail . }

      } 
    GROUP BY ?pl ?pl_label ?abstract ?_thumbnail
```

Comment: IMO Filters are very time consuming.

Comment: Add `DISTINCT` also to `_sameAs` and `?_paradigm_label` in respective projection's `group_concat` to avoid duplicates in the aggregation. Also you probably missed to filter by language ?_paradigm_label since you are interested in "en" literals everywhere else. That also will reduce the size of the result.

Comment: @DamyanOgnyanov Thanks, Using Distinct problem solved !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a dirty data issue in the current http://live.dbpedia.org/sparql, such that there are values from multiple ingestions (i.e., multiple edits of the Wikipedia source page) for some predicates (including `dbo:abstract`, `dbo:influenced`, and `dbo:influencedBy`), where there should only be the most recently ingested value (i.e., the latest edit).  This means that your result set will include something of a Cartesian product -- with some rows that are duplicates except for the predicate(s) that incorrectly deliver multiple versions.

Modulo that data issue, this query (with more than just an additional `DISTINCT`!) will deliver what I believe you now want --

```
SELECT  DISTINCT                                                             ?pl  
                                                                             ?pl_label 
                                                                             ?abstract 
                                                                             ?_thumbnail
        ( group_concat ( DISTINCT ?_influenced_label   ; separator="; " ) AS ?influenced )
        ( group_concat ( DISTINCT ?_influencedBy_label ; separator="; " ) AS ?influencedBy ) 
        ( group_concat ( DISTINCT ?_sameAs             ; separator=", " ) AS ?sameAs )     
        ( group_concat ( DISTINCT ?_paradigm_label     ; separator=", " ) AS ?paradigm )

WHERE
      { 
                      ?pl               rdf:type            dbo:ProgrammingLanguage ;
                                        rdfs:label          ?pl_label
                      FILTER ( LANG ( ?pl_label ) = 'en' ) .

          OPTIONAL  { ?pl               dbo:abstract        ?abstract . 
                      FILTER ( LANG ( ?abstract ) = 'en' ) . }

          OPTIONAL  { ?pl               dbo:influenced      ?_influenced . 
                      ?_influenced      rdfs:label          ?_influenced_label . 
                      FILTER ( LANG ( ?_influenced_label ) = 'en' ) . }

          OPTIONAL  { ?pl               dbo:influencedBy    ?_influencedBy . 
                      ?_influencedBy    rdfs:label          ?_influencedBy_label
                      FILTER ( LANG ( ?_influencedBy_label ) = 'en' ) . }

          OPTIONAL  { ?pl               owl:sameAs          ?_sameAs . } 

          OPTIONAL  { ?pl               dbp:paradigm        ?_paradigm .
                      ?_paradigm        rdfs:label          ?_paradigm_label 
                      FILTER ( LANG ( ?_paradigm_label ) = 'en' ) . }

          OPTIONAL { ?pl                dbo:thumbnail       ?_thumbnail . }

      } 

GROUP BY ?pl ?pl_label ?abstract ?_thumbnail
```

Comment: It works but can you tell me why aggregate function MIN does not work in live endpoint

Comment: @ShajedulIslamAny - This `MIN` related comment is not about this Q/A. You should ask a new question for it. That said -- the live.dbpedia.org/sparql endpoint is apparently having some issues at the moment, which are not specific to the `MIN` function, which are causing the errors you described in the comments at https://stackoverflow.com/a/55380140/241164.