# Sparql query getting duplicate or not I dont understant

Tags: java, sparql

I am using this query to get all programming languages and their details. This is my test class. I have used it in java and it works fine. The problem I am facing is, there is a language named "ML (programming language)"

It prints multiple times with different abstract, different influenced. Not only ML but also some other languages doing this. I don't know is there any problem in my query or its getting exact data as it is.

```
package io.naztech.dbpedia;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.jena.query.ResultSet;
import org.apache.jena.query.ResultSetFormatter;
import org.apache.jena.sparql.engine.http.QueryEngineHTTP;
import org.junit.BeforeClass;
import org.junit.Test;

import io.naztech.talent.model.PediaTag;

public class testDataFetching {

    @Test
    public void testAllDataFetching() {

        String q =  "PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> \n"+
                    "PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> \n"+
                    "PREFIX dbo: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/> \n"+
                    "PREFIX dbp: <http://dbpedia.org/property/> \n"+
                    "PREFIX owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#> \n"+
                    "PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#> \n" +
                    "PREFIX foaf: <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/> \n" +
                    "PREFIX dc: <http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/> \n" +
                    "PREFIX : <http://dbpedia.org/resource/> \n" +
                    "PREFIX dbpedia2: <http://dbpedia.org/property/> \n" +
                    "PREFIX dbpedia: <http://dbpedia.org/> \n" +
                    "PREFIX skos: <http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#> \n" +

                    "SELECT DISTINCT ?pl ?pl_label ?abstract ?_thumbnail \n" +
                    "( Group_concat ( DISTINCT ?_influenced_label; separator= \", \")   AS ?influenced ) \n" + 
                    "( Group_concat ( DISTINCT ?_influencedBy_label; separator= \", \") AS ?influencedBy ) \n" + 
                    "( group_concat ( DISTINCT ?_sameAs; separator=\", \" ) AS ?sameAs ) \n" +
                    "( group_concat ( DISTINCT ?_paradigm_label; separator=\", \" ) AS ?paradigm ) \n" +

                    "WHERE  {\n" +

                    "       ?pl rdf:type dbo:ProgrammingLanguage .\n" + 

                    "       OPTIONAL { ?pl dbo:abstract ?abstract .\n" + 

                    "       FILTER ( LANG ( ?abstract ) = 'en' ) . } \n" + 

                    "       ?pl rdfs:label ?pl_label .\n" + 

                    "       FILTER ( LANG ( ?pl_label ) = 'en' ) .\n" + 

                    "       OPTIONAL { ?pl dbo:influenced ?_influenced . \n" + 

                    "       ?_influenced rdfs:label ?_influenced_label . \n" + 

                    "       FILTER ( LANG ( ?_influenced_label ) = 'en' ) . } \n" + 

                    "       OPTIONAL { ?pl dbo:influencedBy  ?_influencedBy . \n" + 

                    "       ?_influencedBy  rdfs:label ?_influencedBy_label . \n" + 

                    "       FILTER ( LANG ( ?_influencedBy_label ) = 'en' ) . } \n" +

                    "       OPTIONAL { ?pl owl:sameAs ?_sameAs . } \n" +

                    "       OPTIONAL { ?pl dbp:paradigm ?_paradigm . \n" +

                    "       ?_paradigm rdfs:label ?_paradigm_label . } \n" + 

                    "       OPTIONAL { ?pl dbo:thumbnail ?_thumbnail . } \n" +

                    "       }"+

                    "       GROUP BY ?pl ?pl_label ?abstract ?_thumbnail ?influenced ?influencedBy ?sameAs ?paradigm";

        @SuppressWarnings("resource")
        QueryEngineHTTP queryEngine = new QueryEngineHTTP("http://live.dbpedia.org/sparql", q);
        ResultSet results = queryEngine.execSelect();

        int count = 0;

        while (results.hasNext()) 
        {
            QuerySolution qs =  results.next();
            System.out.println("NAME-->\n"+qs.get("pl_label").toString()+"\n");

            if(qs.get("influenced") != null)
            {
            System.out.println("INFLUENCED-->\n"+qs.get("influenced").toString()+"\n"); 
            }
           if(qs.get("influencedBy") != null)
            {
                System.out.println("INFLUENCED BY-->\n"+qs.get("influencedBy").toString()+"\n"); 
            }
           if(qs.get("abstract") != null)
            {
                System.out.println("ABSTRACT-->\n"+qs.get("abstract").toString()+"\n");  
            }

            if(qs.get("sameAs") != null)
            {
                System.out.println("SAME AS-->\n"+qs.get("sameAs").toString()+"\n");  
            }

            if(qs.get("paradigm") != null)
            {
            System.out.println("PARADIGM-->\n"+qs.get("paradigm").toString()+"\n");  
            }

            if(qs.get("_thumbnail") != null)
            {
                System.out.println("THUMBNAIL-->\n"+qs.get("_thumbnail").toString()+"\n");  
            }

            System.out.println("\n");

            count++;
        }

        System.out.println(count);



    }

}
```

Comment: There are 3 English abstracts, look at http://live.dbpedia.org/page/ML_(programming_language)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are 3 English abstracts in the dataset, look at the [DBpedia Live resource](http://live.dbpedia.org/page/ML_(programming_language)).

You can workaround this by removing the `?abstract` variable from the `group by ...` part and instead using an aggregate function (`sample, min, max`) to get any of the abstracts:

```sql
SELECT  ?pl ?pl_label 
        (MIN(?_abstract) AS ?abstract) # <- used MIN here to ensure stable result
        ?_thumbnail 
        (GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT ?_influenced_label ; separator='; ') AS ?influenced) 
        (GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT ?_influencedBy_label ; separator='; ') AS ?influencedBy) 
        (GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT ?_sameAs ; separator=', ') AS ?sameAs) 
        (GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT ?_paradigm_label ; separator=', ') AS ?paradigm)
WHERE
  { ?pl  a  dbo:ProgrammingLanguage ;
         rdfs:label  ?pl_label
    FILTER ( lang(?pl_label) = "en" )

    OPTIONAL
      { ?pl  dbo:abstract  ?_abstract
        FILTER ( lang(?_abstract) = "en" )
      }
    OPTIONAL
      { ?pl       dbo:influenced/rdfs:label  ?_influenced_label
        FILTER ( lang(?_influenced_label) = "en" )
      }
    OPTIONAL
      { ?pl       dbo:influencedBy/rdfs:label  ?_influencedBy_label
        FILTER ( lang(?_influencedBy_label) = "en" )
      }
    OPTIONAL
      { ?pl  owl:sameAs  ?_sameAs }
    OPTIONAL
      { ?pl       dbp:paradigm/rdfs:label  ?_paradigm_label
        FILTER ( lang(?_paradigm_label) = "en" )
      }
    OPTIONAL
      { ?pl  dbo:thumbnail  ?_thumbnail }
  }
GROUP BY ?pl ?pl_label ?_thumbnail
```

#### Update

I'll add the comment from @TallTed here, he's one of the people behind Virtuoso and knows it better than me:

> Be aware that while the recommended aggregate functions (`MIN`, `MAX`,
>   `SAMPLE`) will get ***a*** value of the predicate, there is no assurance that
>   this value will be the latest ingested to the dataset.

Comment: Be aware that while the recommended aggregate functions (`MIN`, `MAX`, `SAMPLE`) will get *a* value of the predicate, there is no assurance that this value will be the latest ingested to the dataset.

Comment: Getting 405 HTTpException When applied this

Comment: It only works if I get data from https://dbpedia.org/sparql but It does not works for https://live.dbpedia.org/sparql but I need to use LIVE endpoint because without using live it gives me results these are not programming language like : sex_education, which is not a programming language. So I need to use live.

Comment: But that's not a problem of my answer/query but of the endpoint. Right now the DBpedia Live endpoint is down: a `HTTP 405` and a message *"The web-site you are currently trying to access is under maintenance at this time.
We are sorry for any inconvenience this has caused."* is returned by any query. You can check this also in the web interface.

Comment: I meant without using Min my query works for Live endpoint but when I use Min then I get 405 error for Live. Is it happening because site is under maintenance? I just tested now, It works at Live without using Min Aggregate function !

Comment: When I try it in the [web interface](http://live.dbpedia.org/sparql) now (at 10:14am) I just get the *"under maintenance"* message. Note, it's a shared service, so it might be busy right now. And you'll never have any guarantees that the service is always online when you run your code.

Comment: And yes, any change in the query can affect the query optimizer and therefore the performance.

Comment: By the way, you could still use your previous query and omit the duplicate in your Java code. That is trivial ...

Comment: Ok Thanks for your response